# How to show selected Datagrid cell value in a textBox?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile

I am developing a Windows Mobile 6.5 application with C# using Visual Studio 2008 (I'm still a beginner), it's connected to an SQL CE database. However, I want to send the value of a selected cell in the dataGrid connected to my database to a textBox. It looks very possible, but I can't find a cell click event related to the dataGrid control, there is only one for the dataGridView that I think it's only available for the Windows Desktop applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, wire up your click event, by selecting the GridView control and double clicking the `Click` field located under the Lightening Bolt:

[image: click event]

Next, expanding on an answer already posted:

```
private void dataGrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  int row = dataGrid1.CurrentCell.RowNumber;
  int col = dataGrid1.CurrentCell.ColumnNumber;
  textBox1.Text = string.Format("{0}", dataGrid1[row, col]);
}
```

I use `string.Format` because sometimes your data could be null or `DBNull.Value`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want the [`Control.Click Event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click.aspx)

> The Click event passes an EventArgs to its event handler, so it only indicates that a click has occurred. If you need more specific mouse information (button, number of clicks, wheel rotation, or location), use the MouseClick event. However, the MouseClick event will not be raised if the click is caused by action other than that of the mouse, such as pressing the ENTER key.

```
private void dataGrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int row_num = _DataGrid.CurrentCell.RowNumber;
    int col_num = _DataGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnNumber;
    object data = _DataGrid[row_num, col_num];
}
```

Comment: I understand, but isn't there a possibility of retrieving the string content of the cell? I tried _DataGrid.CurrentCell.ToString(); but it returns the RowNumber and the ColumnNumber again.

Comment: use _DateGrid[_DataGrid.CurrentCell.RowNumber, _DataGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnNumber] to access the datagrid cell value. Further on, Paul Yao has a nice in-place-edit solution for DataGrid in his book Programming the .Net Compact Framework.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to handle `Click` and make use of [CurrentCell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.currentcell%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) Property